# A word expresses destiny that ties people together

Tags: word-request

In Chinese, there is a word called "yuán fèn", which means the destiny that ties people together, at special time and place. In English, is there one word that can express that meaning?

Comment: I found this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuanfen. I don't know an English word that fits this meaning perfectly. (I know a few words/phrases for it in my first language.) In English, I would probably use either *destiny* or *fate*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent English* word would appear to be **fate**:

> fate  (fāt)
>
> n.
>
> 1. The supposed force, principle, or power that predetermines events: *Fate did not favor his career*. - [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fate)

Fate can be used in the context of individuals (*his fate*, *her fate* etc.), groups (*their fate*, *they were fated* etc.) or as an overarching power (*fate was against them*) in a way that is not quite as applicable to the near synonym **destiny**. Which as [the first definition at thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/destiny) implies is usually used in association with individuals:

> des·ti·ny  (dĕs′tə-nē)
>
> n. pl. des·ti·nies
>
> The inevitable or necessary fate to which a particular person or thing is destined; one's lot.

---

*A [loanword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) that also seems to be a close match is **kismet**.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one word, but the English phrase **we're all in the same boat** seems to convey the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is "no!". There are many cases of words in one language that have no exact equivalent in another language. This makes the life of a professional translator difficult. It is also why to speak a second language well you have to understand it internally without reference and translation into your first language.